Share memory between all users that access website
I have php file that reads big file from HD. I do not want that each user that access the website will cause the php to re read the file from hd. I prefer to read it one time, store it in memory and then php will use this cached memory and not the file after the first init of the memory for all users that access the site.
I tried to store the file content in session but each user has its own session so this will not work. I tried to use Apc and memcache but same results. Each user had its own instance of these object so the memory is not shared and php re read the file for each user access. Is there a way to do what I need? The file content BTW will never changed.
I will add more info to answer your questions. File size is 7mb.
Here is the code using memcached, i tried same logic for Apc with same results:
<?php
class CountryFromIP {
    private static $csvArray;    
    function __construct() 
    {
        try 
        {
            $memcached = new Memcached();
            $memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211); 
            self::$csvArray = $memcached->get('ip_to_country_data');
            if (!self::$csvArray)
            {
                self::$csvArray = file('IpToCountry.txt');
                error_log("Read File");
                $memcached->set('ip_to_country_data', self::$csvArray);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            error_log("Error in IPToCountry constructor: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
     
    function GetCountryName($ip) 
    {
         //here some code to find the country from the IP by searching in self::$csvArray  
    }
}
$ipaddress=getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'):getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$object = new CountryFromIP();
$countryName =  $object->GetCountryName($ipaddress); 
?> 

Seems like that maybe because this code:
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211);
runs for each user, each user has its own instance of Memcached and that is why it does not work as i need (this line error_log("Read File"); is executed for every user which mean file was read from DB on each access to the php)

I tried to use Apc and memcache but same results. Post your code.

memcache is not per-user, so it should work.

Note that by default the maximum size of a memcache item is 1MB. So if the file is very large, you'll need to increase that if you want to store it in one item.

Don't forget that the operating system has its own caches. If you read the file frequently, it will usually be in cache and won't have to go to disk. And if you SSD, disk access is close to memory speed.

Apc is per-process, so it should work too.

How big is this file? How much of it do you need? If it is significantly large, and you need a significant amount of it, do you have enough additional memory beyond your day-to-day usage for it? Is there a reason why you are avoiding a database, which literally exists to be something that multiple users can access, and which can store its data in memory?

I just added the code. BTW file size is 7MB so maybe this is the issue?

I just added the code. BTW file size is 7MB so maybe this is the issue? and i want the file to be stayed in memory for ever since i do search on its content and its content will never change. I just do not see reason why to go to HD or DB to read something for each user when that something will never change

As noted, the default maximum might be 1MB, so it might be worth it to inspect the result of the set operation

My website Is in shared host so not sure I can set max size unless there is option to do that in code

Did you inspect the return value of set to see if there’s a failure?

Thanks Chris you were right set gave me MEMCACHED_CONNECTION_FAILURE even when i added short string. addServer returned ok but i guess it did not really add the server. as for apcu i understand it is per php process and server can open process per each user that surf to the website. I wonder if memcached  do the same, so in this case memcached  will not help as well. BTW in my original code above there is error since i try to save array instead of string to memcached  but as said even when trying to set short string i got MEMCACHED_CONNECTION_FAILURE . So i guess addserver had issue

Yeah, I guess we had assumed that you had the Memcached server installed at least.

It is shared host. I enabled the Memcached. Otherwise it would throw exception when getting to Memcached lines in code. Not sure why .set() is falling.  In my opinion Memcached will act the same as accu. Issue is that cause .set() keep falling i can not check. So  i do not think there is a solution.  Which is strange cause it look reasonable to be to share memory between all php processes..

“I enabled the Memcached” - by that you mean the extension? When you tried APCu, did you also inspect the result of add/store?

Yes I enabled the extension with memcached.  As for apcu, yes I even stored and fetched and I could fetch the data just after I set it, but when trying from another tab or browser,  the data was not there. It was there only on same php process
